# UnionFind data structure implemented in Python

Tags: python, object-oriented, design-patterns

This class is used to create sets out of nodes to from a graph-like structure (or grouping since I remove most of the normal graph structure and all child nodes have the same parent).

Is there anything I can do to improve the design of this class? Is the use of static methods here appropriate?

```
class UnionFind(object):
    '''
    Used to initialize the set and then holds the required functions 
    to operate on them
    '''

    def __init__(self, vertex):
        self.rank = 0
        self.parent = self
        self.vertex = vertex

    @staticmethod
    def find(x):
        if x != x.parent:
            x.parent = UnionFind.find(x.parent)
        return x

    @staticmethod
    def union(x,y):
        xroot = UnionFind.find(x)
        yroot = UnionFind.find(y)

        if xroot == yroot:
            return 
        if xroot.rank > yroot.rank:
            yroot.parent = xroot
        else:
            xroot.parent = yroot
            if xroot.rank == yroot.rank:
                yroot.rank += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

- `find` is not a right name. A method `find(x)` is expected to find objects matching `x`. `find_root` seems more appropriate.

  <sub>I know that Sedgewick & Wayne use `find`, and they are wrong.</sub>
- `find` (or `find_root`) has no reason to be static. `x.find_root()` is way more natural than `UnionFind.find_root(x)`.
- Python does not eliminate tail recursion. I recommend to rewrite `find` as

  ```
  def find(x):
      while x != x.parent:
          x = x.parent
      return x
  ```

Comment: As you suggested dropping the `@staticmethod` decorator, you could write `self` instead of `x`.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Thanks for the suggestion. It is a lot more natural to not have to call find with an argument

Comment: @vnp Thanks! The rewrite of find is much better.